# Can telomere length maintenance be an answer to increased life span of human beings?

Tags: molecular-biology, cancer, telomere

Telomere shortening may prevent the development of cancer in human aged cells by limiting the number of cell divisions. However, shortening of telomeres impairs immune function and thus might also increase susceptibility to cancer.Hence if length of telomere is kept constant, wouldn't it lead to development of cancerous cells rather than increase of life span?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is each generation getting older?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36235/is-each-generation-getting-older)